# JavaScript html errors

Tags: javascript, html

I have been trying to create a html file in JavaScript but it is not working with many errors. please help.

Please see code attached in the screenshot. I am fairly new to this and am not sure if it is a setting issue on VScode or if it's another issue?[image]

Comment: Hello, why do you want to write html in js file? why don't you change the file extension to `.html`?

Comment: I removed the Java tag and put the Javascript tag on.  This question is nothing to do with Java.

Comment: Work on the basics buddy, your mind is all over the place.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 2):

I think you might be a bit confused. There are a couple of ways to do this, but I'll give you two for now:

1. When you want to write HTML in JS file, you have to have an HTML file separate and then target the HTML elements with DOM using javascript.
2. Another approach is to add  in your HTML file and then add your JavaScript logic within it.

This is an example of how you can add JavaScript to your **HTML file**.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Dynamic HTML with JavaScript</title>
</head>
<body>


// JavaScript, your calling elements within HTML using DOM
<script>
    // Create a button element
    const buttonElement = document.createElement('button');

    // Set button properties
    buttonElement.textContent = 'Click me!';
    buttonElement.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
    buttonElement.style.color = 'white';

    // Add a click event listener to the button
    buttonElement.addEventListener('click', function () {
        alert('Button clicked!');
    });

    // Append the button to the body of the document
    document.body.appendChild(buttonElement);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't put HTML in a JavaScript file like that. You have to rename your `test.js` file to `test.html`.

Your JavaScript file is `your-script.js` (as defined in your `<script src="..."></script>`), not `test.js`. You can put JavaScript in this file, not HTML.

An example of your different files is below. Each bit of code will have a potential file name commented at the top. These are just comments so can be removed in your code.

```js
/* index.js */
document.getElementById("fontChangerBtn").addEventListener("click", function() { // on button click
    if(document.body.style.fontFamily != "Merriweather") { // check if font is Merriweather
        document.body.style.fontFamily = "Merriweather"; // change font to Merriweather
    } else {
        document.body.style.fontFamily = "sans-serif"; // change font to default
    }
});
```

```css
/* styles.css */
.my-rainbow-background {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, violet, indigo, blue, green, yellow, orange, red);
  background-size: 1400% 100%; /* increase the background size to cover all colors */
  animation: rainbowAnimation 25s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes rainbowAnimation {
  0% {
    background-position: 0% 50%;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 100% 50%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- index.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap 5 Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Merriweather&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container-fluid p-5 my-rainbow-background text-white text-center">
    <h1>Example Web Page</h1>
    <p>Press the button below to change the font to/from Merriweather.</p>
    <button class="btn btn-light" id="fontChangerBtn">Change Fonts</button>
  </div>
  
  <div class="container mt-5">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <h3>Column 1</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit...</p>
        <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris...</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <h3>Column 2</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit...</p>
        <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris...</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <h3>Column 3</h3>        
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit...</p>
        <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris...</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Remember to link each file to the HTML file (SO does this automatically in examples), for example you can link `styles.css` with:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
```

Your `index.js` file can be linked with:

```
<script src="index.js"></script>
```

Preferably have your `<link>` tags at the top of the page and `<script>` tags at the bottom of the page to improve site speed.